# Objective C - Constraints not working properly when adding Subview on older Phones

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have a screen with two tabs which I use two xib files for each tab. So in the first tab, I have a view and when I switch to another tab, I switch to  another view. I'm using a container to switch the views, I added the subviews to the container like this:

[image: Adding the two views to container]

So when I need to switch the views (which means I switched tabs) I do it like this:

[image: Switch from view one to view two]

*Same for vwNadaConstaStatus, just switch from vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio to vwNadaConstaStatus*

I have a problem with the vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio though, this is the view I'm talking about:

[image: vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio with Image Icon Constraints]

[image: vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio with Label Description Constraints]

You see there are constraints, and they are working properly when I viewing with several iPhones. The problem is, when I run it to the simulator it simply won't work like it does in the xib view. This is what happens when it is running on the simulator:

[image: e vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio running on simulator]

You see vwNadaConstaHistoricoVazio constraints aren't the way they were supposed to be (horizontally aligned).

Do you guys have any idea what is happening?

Edit: These are the vwContainer constraints:

[image: vwContainer Constraints]

Comment: I think your constraints are correct, but the constraints on `_vwContainer` is what is causing your problem.  Could you share the constraints that you have on `_vwContainer`?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Done

Comment: Can you debug and figure out if maybe the container frame is different from what you are expecting.  The constraints on your label and image look correct.